# replace all youtube iframes before cookie consent accepted

Tags: php, wordpress, gdprconsentform

This is for the GDPR cookie policy.
Because youtube use cookies, I have to block the youtube videos, and only grant access if the cookie policy is accepted.

so I need something like:

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['consentaccept'])) {
    // replace all iframes from https://www.youtube.com/ with:
    //<div class="youtubeblock">you must enable cookies to view this video</div>
}
```

or maybe you have a better solution

Any ideas?

It is WordPress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [`template_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/) hook, you have access to all the HTML that will be rendered to the page. You can use this hook to turn on [Output Buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php), find and replace anything you want, and then return the output back, whether it's been modified or not.

> Keep in mind this won't cover any iframes that are *loaded dynamically* with lazy loading, AJAX requests, etc - but anything that's loaded into the HTML at runtime will be in here.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'global_find_replace', 99 );
function global_find_replace(){
    ob_start( function( $buffer ){
        /**
         *`$buffer` contains your entire markup for this page, at run time.
         * anything dynamically loaded with JS/Ajax, etc won't be in here
         */

        // Did they accept the GDPR cookie?
        if( !isset($_COOKIE['gdpr_consent']) ){
            // Nope. Build a simple "accept cookies" notice
            $notice = '<div class="accept-cookies">You must accept cookies to see this content</div>';

            // Replace all youtube iframes regardless of class, id, other attributes, with our notice
            $buffer = preg_replace( '/<iframe.+src="https?:\/\/(?:www.)?youtu\.?be(?:\.com)?.+<\/iframe>/i', $notice, $buffer );
        }

        // Always return the buffer, wither it was modified or not.
        return $buffer;
    });
}
```

Here's the regex I whipped up for the youtube videos, feel free to modify it if I missed anything: https://regex101.com/r/2ZQOvk/2/

This should be more than enough to get you started though!